# Web SVN for Windows?

Tags: svn

Is there an equivalent for Windows? http://www.websvn.info/features/

Comment: Yes, VisualSVN Server 3.2 has a new web UI for Subversion repos, take a look at the demo here http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can integrate PHP into IIS and run WebSVN on there.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) we have been using it for over 2 years now and its just fantastic. The server is absolutely free. You can use normal tortoise SVN client [free again] with the server without any problems at all.

If you intend to use their Visual Studio.Net add-in, then you might have to shell out 50$ per user license. this is absolutely optional, we have taken up the licenses and i must say that its really handy to have your SVN operations from within .Net IDE.

Comment: I don't want to use Tortoise inside VS.  Thanks though.  I do use Visual SVN server.

Comment: I'm talking about web access to repositories, not a client to create them or use subversion within VS.  Two different topics.

Comment: VisualSVN, while really good easy-to-install Windows SVN server, doesn't have the best web interface. Its there, its functional, it's.. lacking many features other ones have.

Comment: i had probably gone on a slightly different track - here is a web based SVN application for windows http://www.sublimesvn.com/

Answer (score 1):

websvn can be installed using apache and php on windows

Comment: [Article](http://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/How-to-Setup-Subversion-2b-Apache-2b-WebSVN-on-Windows.aspx) on how to install WebSVN on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/), it's similar. You are able to browse your repositories via browser.

[image]
<sub>(source: [visualsvn.com](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/manager-small.png))</sub>

Comment: Yes, but I want to get a list of all without manually having to copy the URL from that client

Comment: copying the url into a browser cannot find the page.

Comment: You dont have to copy url (the screenshot is just about the UI). Common problem with VisualSVN, that it uses certificate - and ie. Opera hate that. But with IE you should able to open http://MACHINENAME:YOURPORT.

Comment: Step-by-step config: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/doc/server-config/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). Its written in python, which means its cross platform, and is possibly the most well integrated wiki/issue tracking system to SVN going. If you use VisualSVN Server (and you should), its [very easy to install](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/).

Trac has a very nice web browser, amongst its other features (all of which can be turned off if desired)

Otherwise, assuming you're running subversion through Apache, you can install any of the web-based viewers. Some are more difficult to get going (eg Insurrection, which relies a lot on mod_rewrite, which was too tricky in the end for me to install on Windows) but most are simple.